# Make variable variable accessible outside of loop

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

I am trying to make a looped variable variable accessible outside of the loop. Everything works, but I am having trouble with this piece of the code:

```
$dayVar."_count" = $dayVarCount;
```

The full code is below:

```
<?php

$day_1="sep_28";
$day_2="sep_29";
$day_3="sep_30";

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '$id'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{

for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) 
    {
        $dayVar = "day_".$i;
        $dayVarCount = $row[$$dayVar];
        echo $$dayVar . ': ' . $dayVarCount . '<br>';

        $dayVar."_count". = $dayVarCount;
    }      
}

echo "$day_3_count";

?>
```

Comment: Please describe what is your trouble. IE: what you actually have, and what your expect to have. By the way, the expression `$dayVar."_count". = $dayVarCount;` cannot be a variable assignation.

Comment: Could you please provide us with the error message you are getting?

Comment: What is the significance of `$day_1="sep_28";`? is this important to what you're trying to do - I think that the answers might change if so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i believe that your variable assignment of of $dayVar."_count" is incorrect or illegal. i would try ${$dayVar."_count"} instead.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know you could do that in php.

Answer (score 0):

As Skrol29 rightly says, that line can not work:

An assignment (assigning a value to a veriable) always has the form

```
<variablename> <assignmentoperator> <value>
```

in php that means:

```
$day_1 = "123"
```

as you have already used.

Variable names are not usually not generic. If you need such functionality, use arrays.
[PHP arrays](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 0):

You're almost in the rightplace.. but.

```
 for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++)  
    { 
        $dayVar = "day_".$i; 
        $dayVarCount = $dayVar."_count";
    $$dayVarCount =  $row[$$dayVar];   
    }       


echo "$day_3_count";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 <?php
 // Connect to server and select database.
$host   =   "host here";
$username="username here";
$password="pass here";
$db_name="db here";
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
   if(mysql_select_db("$db_name")){echo "Success";}else{echo "cannot select DB";}



   $day_1="sep_28";
   $day_2="sep_29";
   $day_3="sep_30";
   $id=1;
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tab1` WHERE id = '$id'");

   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
   {

   for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) 
   {
    $dayVar = "day_".$i;
    $dayVarCount = $row[$$dayVar];
    echo $$dayVar . ': ' . $dayVarCount . '<br>';

    ${$dayVar."_count"} = $dayVarCount;
  }      
  }

  echo "$day_3_count";

 ?>


  <?php
   // close connection
  mysql_close();
  ?>
```